# Link to Method,Doxygen C++

Tags: c++, methods, struct, doxygen

I have a struct like this

```
namespace color_space {

    /**
     * @struct ColorModel
     * @brief Base of all color models to be created.
     * @tparam C The child model typename.
     * @tparam T The child model's component typename.
     * @note You must have public field std::array<T,SIZE> components in your struct/class for operator overloading to work right.
     * Otherwise the behaviour is undefined.
     */
    template<typename C, typename T>
    struct ColorModel {

        /**
         * Get the const begin iterator of components array
         * @return Child's components' array constant end iterator.
         */
        constexpr inline const T* cbegin() const {
            return static_cast<const C*>(this)->components.cbegin();
        }

        /**
         * @see ColorModel#cbegin()
         */
        constexpr inline const T* begin() const {
            return cbegin();
        }
      ...
    }
}
```

I want to link `cbegin()` function in my `begin() const` function documentation, but it is not working. I am using `Clion`. Thx for any help.

Comment: Which doxygen version? What is in your doxygen configuration settings file , different from the default settings?

Answer (score 2):

The used doxygen version is missing as well as the doxygen settings used, with version 1.8.20 I get for all situations in:

```
        /**
         * @see With hash ColorModel#cbegin()
         * @see with double colon ColorModel::cbegin()
         * @see bare cbegin()
         */
```

a link (in this case I would advise to use just the "bare" version).
I'm using a default doxygen configuration stettings file.

Comment: I don't know, in CLion I just type `/**` after that I hit `Enter` and it generates a Doxygen for me

Comment: Well you will have installed in one way or the other doxygen. Probably in a command prompt you can give `doxygen -v` and see the used version.

Comment: Does it work now for you? When not publish a small example including the differences in your "Doxyfile" compared to the default doxygen settings (doxygen -x`).

Comment: So please publish a complete small example including the differences in your "Doxyfile" compared to the default doxygen settings (`doxygen -x`). Must be very subtle. Also try with a default Doxyfile and with an example with just the lines in your example (without the `...`).